# C# - Generic function to modify data structures specific to each type

Tags: c#, generics

I am having some trouble with generics.

I want to write a generic function that given a type, modifies a data structure of that type.

```
public static Dictionary<int, User> Users = new Dictionary<int, User>();
public static Dictionary<int, Item> Items = new Dictionary<int, Item>();
public static Dictionary<int, Store> Stores = new Dictionary<int, Store>();

public static void AddStuff<T>(T stuffToAdd)
{
    (What dict goes here?).TryAdd(stuffToAdd.Id, stuffToAdd)
}
```

I want to call it like:

```
AddStuff<User>(some_user);
```

So depending on what type it's called with, I have to figure out how to find the data structure associated with that type and add/remove stuff from it.  Any ideas for me?

Edit: I have 20 of these dictionaries.

Comment: do you really need a generic? it would have a much better performance if you just had overloads. i don't see a difference in the usage

Comment: I agree with @NevilleNazerane . This does raise the question as to why you are utilizing generics when you have a clearly finite and minimal amount of dictionaries.

Comment: That was just an example. I have 20 of these dictionaries. Should I still make a specific add function for each of them?

Comment: yes, look at all solutions below. everything needs you to do some extra work for each dictionary. the only way to escape it is by using reflection and dynamic. These are usually last resorts. Reflection is very heavy and dynamic is really risky

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am having some trouble with generics.

Yes you are. Pay attention to that feeling. It is telling you that you are abusing generics.

> I want to write a generic function that given a type, modifies a data structure of that type.

My best advice is: stop wanting that.  Generics are supposed to be **generic**. That's why they're called **generics**.  If you are doing *different* things based on the generic type argument then your code is not *generic*.

> I want to call it like:  `AddStuff<User>(some_user);`

Stop wanting that.

Instead, write three methods, and call them like:

```
AddUserStuff(someUser);
AddItemStuff(someItem);
AddStoreStuff(someStore);
```

and so on.  You logically have three methods that do three different things, so **they are not generic**.  Write three methods!

> Edit: I have 20 of these dictionaries.

Write 20 methods. It's not hard, and it is *easier* than writing a "generic" method that has twenty cases and is then a bug farm because it looks generic but really is not.

Comment: My question was originally just an example but I actually have 20 of these dictionaries for various types throughout my product. Should I have 20 of these methods that do the same thing?

Comment: @noblerare: Your choices are: write 20 methods, or write one method that has 20 cases, and is then a bug farm when you add a 21st dictionary and forget to add the case to your "generic" method that is not actually generic. **The former is both easier and safer**.

Comment: @noblerare: But this would be a good opportunity to also revisit the architectural decision that led you to have twenty different dictionaries all keyed on an int. Suppose instead you made your entities identified by a unique identifier -- a Guid. Now you can build *one* dictionary that maps `Guid` to `object`.

Comment: with all this generics, why don't you use something that is built in to handle data stores? They already have all the functions you are looking for

Comment: @noblerare: More generally, ask yourself whether there's an opportunity for automation here. You have some factory that is handing out users and associating ids with them.  Maybe the *factory object* should be providing the service *automatically* of doing an id-to-object lookup.  Why are you calling a method at all to add an item to a dictionary? Make that an implementation detail of the factory.

Comment: It is rare for me to disagree with an @EricLippert answer, but if you have the need for common functionality against an already generic type, using generics within a method seems perfectly sensible and not an 'abuse' of generics. The missing piece is around a shared interface (and possibly an approach for a typed  'dictionary of dictionaries', but that is likely an architectural mistake). That said, I agree with Eric's comments prodding the larger architectural decisions backing the question.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing your usage `AddStuff<User>(some_user)`, which could also be `AddStuff(some_user)`, I don't see the point of having a generic. Instead of using something that can't be compile-time validated (is the generic `User`, `Item` or `Store` or something else). For instance, `AddStuff<string>("oops invalid usage")` would give a runtime issue. You might as well use overloads for each type. You can have a private helper function such as Paul's extension example.

Using something like John Wu's idea of using `IHasId` interface, you can create a private helper like this:

```
private static void AddStuff<T>(Dictionary<int, T> dict, T stuffToAdd)
    where TValue  : IHasId
{
    dict.TryAdd(stuffToAdd.Id, stuffToAdd)
}
```

You can use it and create simple overloads:

```
public static void AddStuff(User user) => AddStuff(Users, user);
public static void AddStuff(Item item) => AddStuff(Items, item);
public static void AddStuff(Store store) => AddStuff(Stores, store);
```

Comment: Paul deleted his answer. he had posted an extension function for `Dictionary<int, T>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a if/else if or switch (C#7 up only) to accomplish this.

```
public static void AddStuff<T>(T stuffToAdd)
{
    switch (stuffToAdd)
    case User:
        Users.TryAdd(stuffToAdd.Id, stuffToAdd);
    // More cases
}
```

P.S.: on mobile and on bus. So please make necessary corrections to make it compile etc. Also as others pointed out, you don't actually need generic here. So don't use what I've shown here!

Comment: This is not possible. See here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/peterhal/2005/07/05/many-questions-switch-on-type/

Comment: @Impurity - It is possible in C#6, although the use of generics is redundant since it would work if `stuffToAdd` had type `object`.

Comment: Ah, I stand correctly. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @lee could u plz provide a reference?tnx in advance

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements @daniel

Comment: @DanielB - See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: type pattern matching in switches was added in C# 7.0.

Comment: @Eric okay thanks. So I was correct before the wrong "correction". So I uncorrected the wrong correction to make it correct again :D

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access the Id property, you need a common interface and a type constraint. In my example I include an `IHasId` interface so all domain types have that ID available.

To pick the dictionary, you just need to arrange them in a bigger dictionary. In my example I call this `dictionaries`.

```
//This interface allows you to specify a type constraint so AddStuff can use the Id property
public interface IHasId
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public class User  : IHasId { public int Id { get; set; } }
public class Item  : IHasId { public int Id { get; set; } }
public class Store : IHasId { public int Id { get; set; } }

public class Program
{
    public static Dictionary<int, User> Users = new Dictionary<int, User>();
    public static Dictionary<int, Item> Items = new Dictionary<int, Item>();
    public static Dictionary<int, Store> Stores = new Dictionary<int, Store>();

    //This "outer" dictionary will allow AddStuff to look up the right dictionary based on the type.
    public static Dictionary<Type,IDictionary> dictionaries = new Dictionary<Type,IDictionary>
    {
        { typeof(User ), Users },
        { typeof(Item ), Items }, 
        { typeof(Store), Stores}
    };

    public static void AddStuff<TValue>(TValue stuffToAdd) where TValue  : IHasId
    {
        IDictionary d = dictionaries[typeof(TValue)] as Dictionary<int, TValue>;
        d.Add(stuffToAdd.Id, stuffToAdd);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        AddStuff( new User  { Id = 1} );
        AddStuff( new User  { Id = 2} );
        AddStuff( new Item  { Id = 3} );
        AddStuff( new Item  { Id = 4} );
        AddStuff( new Store { Id = 5} );
        AddStuff( new Store { Id = 6} );

        Console.WriteLine("Users:  " + string.Join(",", Users.Select( u => u.Value.Id )));
        Console.WriteLine("Items:  " + string.Join(",", Items.Select( i => i.Value.Id )));
        Console.WriteLine("Stores: " + string.Join(",", Stores.Select( s => s.Value.Id )));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Users:  1,2
Items:  3,4
Stores: 5,6
```

[Link to DotNetFiddle example that works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E0zngG)